# Calcular la nota media de unos Jtextfield

Tags: java, textfield

Estoy haciendo un programilla para guardar las notas de mis alumnos en unos Textfield y que me lo pase una BBDD.

Esto lo hace, pero ahora quiero hallar la nota media en función de los Textfield rellenos. Tengo 5 Textfields, si los relleno todos no hay problema, el problema me viene si no los relleno. Además, quiero que el botón de Calcular no se active hasta que estén rellenos.

Si lo hiciera por pantalla lo tendría claro con un Scanner pedir número de notas y hacer media, pero de forma gráfica no sé cómo hacerlo.

Debería pedir primero el número de notas a hacer la media (pedido en un Textfield), luego rellenarlos con las notas y calcularla?
Espero haberme explicado.

[image: Pantallazo del programilla]

Answer (score 0):

en principio para realizar un cálculo indistintamente si los 5 Jtextfield se encuentran completos, podes usar un Event Listener para detectar cambios en tus JTextFields. Cuando el usuario ingresa datos en un JTextField, se activará y podrá iniciar el cálculo indistintamente si todos estan completos o no.

Por ejemplo:

```
// agrego event listener al JTextFields
field1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
       
        //Alguna validación de datos por aca...

        double resultado = calculo(field1.getText(), field2.getText(), field3.getText());
    }
});
```

Respecto al botón, lo mismo:

```
field1.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        // chequeo que todos los JTextField esten completos
        if (field1.getText().isEmpty() || field2.getText().isEmpty() || field3.getText().isEmpty()) {
            return;
        }

        // muestro el botón
        button.setVisible(true);
    }
});
```

Nota: Lo que no entiendo es que si bien quieres mostrar el botón Calcular sólo cuando los campos estén completos, también quieres que la nota media se calcule antes de que todos las notas estén completas. O simplemente el botón calcular realiza otro calculo, si es así, no tengas en cuenta esta nota.

Comment: Hola Nicolás, 
Lo primero perdón por tardar en contestar. Lo segundo muchas gracias por darme una opción.
El botón calcular quería que se activara cuando están todas las notas puestas, pero también me doy cuenta que hay asignaturas que puede que tengan solo 2 notas o 3 y no las 5. Por lo que igual es mejor que lo deje activado.